# nested for loop java

Tags: java, user-interface, loops, for-loop

I have a homework project I was seriously stuck on. Or pretty much just 1 part of it and need help figuring out. I'm basically using java to create random size buildings and inside those buildings I will create random windows. So far i got random buildings down but I only got 1 window to pop up on each building. when I try to nest a for loop it moves my windows to the end of the screen. I feel like the issue is in the x coordinates and need to somehow reset it. Any help will be appreciated. The program is in 3 parts a building class, panel, and main.
It's my second semester of programming so i'm really fairly new.

PS. I've already turned it in and got credit but I still really want to know how to do this part of the program.

```
/**Written by Paul Ancajima 
* last updated 2/25/15
* RandomSkyline panel
* this is where i bring over Building and have them draw itself
*/
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SkylinePanel extends JPanel{

    //initialize variables
    private int x=5+(int)(Math.random()*((10-5))+1);
    private int w;
    private int l=120+(int)(Math.random()*((300-120)+1));
    private int x1;
    private int y1=150+(int)(Math.random()*((170-150))+1);
    private int gap = 2+(int)(Math.random()*5-2);
    //first windowX and windowY start at 0,0
    private int windowX=5+(int)(Math.random()*((15-5))+1);
    private int windowY = (y1)+(int)(Math.random()*((130-y1))+1);
    private int starX=25+(int)(Math.random()*((50-25))+1);  
    private int roadX;
    private int roadX2=10;
    //random number of windows
    private int winNum = (int)(Math.random()*5*x);
    //arrays or buildings, windows,and stars;
                          //figure out how to use winNum
    private Building[]windowArr= new Building[x]; 
    private Star[]starArr = new Star[starX];
    private Building[]buildingArr = new Building[x];   

    public SkylinePanel(){

        //loop to create all the buildings
        for(int y=0; y<buildingArr.length; y++){

            buildingArr[y] = new Building(x1, y1, w, l, x, Color.blue);
            x1=w+gap+x1;
            y1=(int)(Math.random()*20)+120;
            w=20+(int)+(Math.random()*((35-20))+1);
            l=(int)(Math.random()*300)+80;
            gap = 2+(int)(Math.random()*5-2);

            //FIX THE LOOP
            //for(int zz=0; zz<buildingArr.length; zz++){
            windowArr[y]= new Building(windowX,windowY, 3, 3, x, Color.yellow);
            windowX = x1+(int)(Math.random()*(((x1+(w-gap))-x1))+1);
            windowY = 160+(int)(Math.random()*((y1-(160)))+1);  
            //  }

            for(int zz=0; zz<starArr.length; zz++){
                starArr[zz]= new Star((int)(Math.random()*x1), 0+(int)(Math.random()*((100+0))+1), 1, 1,Color.yellow);
            }

            //the Dimension of the screen will be the size of width of all buildings plus all gaps = x1+w+gap
            setPreferredSize (new Dimension(x1, 200));
            setBackground (Color.black);
        }

    }

    public void paintComponent (Graphics page){

        super.paintComponent(page);
        page.setColor(Color.black);

        for(int i = 0; i<starArr.length;i++){
            starArr[i].draw(page);
        }

        //loop to draw all the buildings
        for(int i=0; i<buildingArr.length; i++){
            buildingArr[i].draw(page);
        }

        //loop to draw all windows(needs work/ change to windowsArr.length)
        for(int i=0; i<buildingArr.length; i++){
            windowArr[i].draw(page);
        }

        page.setColor(Color.white);
        page.fillOval(x1-35, 30, 30, 30);
        page.setColor(Color.gray);
        page.fillRect(0, 180, x1, 20);
        page.setColor(Color.yellow);

        for(int j=0; j<180; j++){
            page.drawLine(roadX, 190, roadX2, 190);
            roadX=roadX+20;
            roadX2=roadX2+20;
        }
    }
}








 /**Written by Paul Ancajima
 * Building class
 * last updated 2/25/15
 */

import java.awt.*;

public class Building{

    private int x,y, width, height,window; private Color color;

    public Building(int x1, int y1, int w, int h, int window, Color shade){

        x= x1;
        y=y1;
        width =w;
        height = h;
        color = shade;
    }

    public int setX(int x1){

        return x1;
    }

    public int setY(int y1){

        return y1;

    }

    public int getWidth(int w){

        return w;
    }

    public int getHeight(int h){

        return h;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics page){

        page.setColor(color);
        page.fillRect(x, y, width, height);

    }

    public void getWindows(int x,int y,int w,int h,Color shade){

        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        width=w;
        height=h;
        color=shade;
    } 
}

/**written by Paul Ancajima
* Skyline main 
* last updated 2/25/15
*/

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class RandomSkyline{

    public static void main (String[] args){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Paul's city");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new SkylinePanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    } 

}
```

Comment: you've got a window array which is of type building? looks to me that your design is bad. Shouldn't a `Building` have a collection of `Windows` that can be positioned based on the building's position?

Comment: that would be awesome but i'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Building` class needs to contain an array of Windows, if you want more than one window per Building. ie

```
public class Building{

    private int x,y, width, height,window; private Color color;
    private Window[] windows = new Window[];  // This could also be done with a collection rather than an array, they are easier to work with if you are adding and removing.

    public Building(int x1, int y1, int w, int h, int window, Color shade){

        x= x1;
        y=y1;
        width =w;
        height = h;
        color = shade;
    }

...

    // Change getWindows to the following
    public Window[] getWindows(){
        return windows;
    } 

    // add a method to generate the windows for the building.  
    public void createWindows(int numWindows) {
        // initialise Window array based on parameter
        windows = new Window[numWindows];

        // loop through for the length of the array
        for (int i = 0; i < windows.size; i++) {
            windows[i] = new Window(); // insert whatever parameters you want for the window.  You probably need to check they stay inside the bounds of the building at least.
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks im working on it right now. looks like i have to provide a dimension or a number in the Window[]windows = new Window[].

Comment: the part where windows[i] = new Window(); says the constructor Window() is not visible not sure what that means

Comment: make sure that in your Window class the constructor Window() is defined as public --> public Window() { .. }

Comment: there is no Window class. I think I am suppose to create windows from the building class using a method. Sorry its hard for me to explain things i dont understand fully.